# Django: Adding CSS classes when rendering form fields in a template

Tags: python, django, forms

I'm outputting fields of a form in a template like this `{{ form.first_name }}` and I'd like to add a class (eg. blueprint's *span-x*-class) to it. So I'd like to know if there's a nice readymade solution (template filter) for that, which I could use in the fashion `{{ form.first_name|add_class:"span-4" }}`? (I just want to know if Django's developers or anybody has thought of that yet without my knowledge before doing it on my own)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

To solve this I made my own template filter, you can apply it on any tag, not just input elements!

```
class_re = re.compile(r'(?<=class=["\'])(.*)(?=["\'])')
@register.filter
def add_class(value, css_class):
    string = unicode(value)
    match = class_re.search(string)
    if match:
        m = re.search(r'^%s$|^%s\s|\s%s\s|\s%s$' % (css_class, css_class, 
                                                    css_class, css_class), 
                                                    match.group(1))
        print match.group(1)
        if not m:
            return mark_safe(class_re.sub(match.group(1) + " " + css_class, 
                                          string))
    else:
        return mark_safe(string.replace('>', ' class="%s">' % css_class))
    return value
```

Comment: Very nicely done. To make it work for fields that end with '/>', I have used `return mark_safe(string.replace(' ', ' class="%s" ' % css_class))` - used a space instead of '>' so that it will find the first space and inject the attribute before the rest.

Comment: The regexp matches greedy, but should be matching lazy. I've altered above's code to ``class_re = re.compile(r'(?<=class=["\'])(.*?)(?=["\'])')``. Otherwise it matches to the last ``"`` char instead of end of class.

Answer (score 52):

You only need to install Django widget_tweaks

```
pip install django-widget-tweaks
```

After you can to do something like that on your template:

```
{{ form.search_query|attr:"type:search" }}
```

--

Read all about it [here](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-widget-tweaks).

Comment: I was looking how to add classes to the `labels`, the I remember that it is straightforward to add them manually: `<label class="the-class" for="{{ field.auto_id }}">{{ field.label }}</label>`

Answer (score 19):

Another way is to use the `as_widget` method on a field to alter it -- simpler and safer than the regex approach, and doesn't require any additional dependencies.

Define a [custom template filter](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-template-tags/):

```
@register.filter
def add_class(field, class_name):
    return field.as_widget(attrs={
        "class": " ".join((field.css_classes(), class_name))
    })
```

And in your template:

```
{{ form.first_name|add_class:"span-4" }}
```

You can also use `as_widget` to add other attributes, like `placeholder`, etc.

Comment: Love this elegant solution, plus I now learned how to use template tags.  Thanks!

Answer (score 12):

A few extra notes on how to get going with Lazerscience's very handy solution. Here's how the file looks with dependency imports:

```
import re
from django.utils.safestring import mark_safe
from django import template
register = template.Library()

class_re = re.compile(r'(?<=class=["\'])(.*)(?=["\'])')
@register.filter
def add_class(value, css_class):
    string = unicode(value)
    match = class_re.search(string)
    if match:
        m = re.search(r'^%s$|^%s\s|\s%s\s|\s%s$' % (css_class, css_class, 
                                                    css_class, css_class), 
                                                    match.group(1))
        print match.group(1)
        if not m:
            return mark_safe(class_re.sub(match.group(1) + " " + css_class, 
                                          string))
    else:
        return mark_safe(string.replace('>', ' class="%s">' % css_class))
    return value
```

I pasted this into a file called add_class.py. The directory structure is:
mydjangoproject > general_tools_app > templatetags > add_class.py

general_tools_app is an application which collects useful functionality like this that I add to new django projects.

(The general_tools_app and templatetags directories both have an empty `__init__.py` file so that they get registered correctly)

In settings.py, my INSTALLED_APPS tuple includes the entry 'mydjangoproject.general_tools_app'.

To use the filter in a template, I add the line `{% load add_class %}` at the top of the file. If I want to add the class 'delete' to a field, I'd do this

```
{{ myfield|add_class:'delete' }}
```

Comment: I found the `class_re` definition a bit too greedy, and ended up in some fields the class was getting entered into the `type` attribute instead of `class`. My revised version: `class_re = re.compile(r'(?<=class=["\'])([^"\']*)(["\'])')`

Answer (score 4):

I am still learning Django, but couldn't you do this something like this -

```
from django import forms

class SomeForm(forms.Form):
    f = forms.CharField(label='x',widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'name'}))
```

I guess there is no need to do this at the template level (or use filters) unless you have some requirement that I did not understand.

Comment: It is much cleaner to separate the style (css) from the functionality (the form). For example, how do you conditionally add a class to a form field in the template using this method? Also, how do you display this form different ways without duplicating the form such as a mobile friendly form and a not so mobile friendly form? The validation provided by the form does not change, but the view of it does.

Comment: The CSS class applied at form level does not impact on different displays. The form class should remain the same on any device and you should have specific css file configuration specialized by device, when needed.

Comment: This is the correct answer, for most cases anyway. No need to mess around with regexes! Just maybe also mention the case for ModelForm:  
 `class Meta: widgets={'f': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'name'})}`

Answer (score 3):

One more note on lazerscience's solution: if you apply this to a <select> element with no class attribute, the string replace in the else case would produce something like this:

```
<select name="state" id="id_state" class="class1 class2">
    <option value="AL" class="class1 class2">Alabama</option class="class1 class2">
    <option value="AK" class="class1 class2">Alaska</option class="class1 class2">
    <option value="AZ" class="class1 class2">Arizona</option class="class1 class2">
</select class="class1 class2">
```

I'm pretty sure browsers scrap those extraneous class definitions, but that's a lot of string replaces when you only need one. An easy remedy for this:

```
return mark_safe(string.replace('>', ' class="%s">' % css_class, 1))
```

That last argument (1) will ensure that only the first instance of ">" will be replaced with "class="...">, which is logically correct for any form element.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the inspiration, guess I never used it with a `select` yet!

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the widget explicitly and add the class using the [`attrs` keyword argument](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/widgets/#django.forms.Widget.attrs). There is no other way that I know of.

However, if this is too cumbersome, you could still just wrap the field in another element, such as div or span and add a class to that. Then modify your CSS accordingly.

Comment: As I already mentioned I'd like to do it in the template, because the form can be rendered in various appearances!

Comment: For optimized results you should consider reading about responsive layouts. Your templates and classes should be unchanged and all the magic remains on css.

Answer (score 0):

## Updated for python3

It was simple to update, just needed parenthesis on the print and a change of unicode(value) to str(value), I also just quickly changed the ' class="%s">' to an fstring.

```
import re
from django.utils.safestring import mark_safe
from django import template
register = template.Library()

class_re = re.compile(r'(?<=class=["\'])(.*)(?=["\'])')
@register.filter
def add_class(value, css_class):
    string = str(value)
    match = class_re.search(string)
    if match:
        m = re.search(r'^%s$|^%s\s|\s%s\s|\s%s$' % (css_class, css_class, 
                                                    css_class, css_class), 
                                                    match.group(1))
        print (match.group(1))
        if not m:
            return mark_safe(class_re.sub(match.group(1) + " " + css_class, 
                                          string))
    else:
        return mark_safe(string.replace('>', f' class="{css_class}">'))
    return value
```